# Unbound classpath variable junit and log4j when importing a libgdx project in to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to import and run the project listed here:

[Scene2d Actions and Event Handling](http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/01/31/libgdx-example-of-using-scene2d-actions-and-event-handling/)

I start by downloading the zip file and then importing it in to eclipse. From here I get the following three errors (after resolving others pertaining to incorrect android version):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath variable: 'M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.5/junit-4.5.jar' in project 'game-test-desktop'  game-test-desktop       Build path  Build Path Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath variable: 'M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.5/junit-4.5.jar' in project 'netthreads-libgdx'  netthreads-libgdx       Build path  Build Path Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath variable: 'M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar' in project 'netthreads-libgdx'    netthreads-libgdx       Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the problem? I have noticed that this junit should be included in the JDT for eclipse but I have installed that with no change in the error. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the package has some odd dependencies on that user's libGDX checkout (the "netthreads-libgdx" is not the standard libGDX).  What version of libGDX do you have installed?

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that the project has dependencies on libraries which are managed with **Maven**, which Eclipse isn't automatically setup to handle.

You'll need to first [download](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) and then [install Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation).  Then you can open a command-line window and run `mvn install` from your project directory, which will build the code and pull down any required dependencies.

Lastly, you'll need to go into Eclipse and set it up to that it's aware of your local Maven repository...

1. Window -> Preferences
2. Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables -> New
3. `name` will be `M2_REPO`
4. `path` will be something like `c:\users\drew\.m2\repository`
5. Click the OK button twice

If you do a recompile in Eclipse, those errors should go away.

Comment: Hi, how can I set this up for every new instance of eclipse I open.  I always have to set it for each new eclipse instance.

Comment: seems to be broken in Eclipse 4.4.1 on Mavericks

Comment: Better to make it environment variable in windows/linux,this way you can switch to any IDE,
And also after this change clean your project and restart eclipse/IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Drew, but also restart your eclipse after.

Comment: This is rather a comment to the answer and not an answer. Please use comments.